# New close reason for when question does not show any research effort?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, close-reasons

Questions that don't show any research effort usually get closed with the reason "unclear" or "too broad."

However, some questions are perfectly clear and specific, yet not acceptable due to lack of effort. For example:

- I want to do X. Please write code for me.

  - Example: [Creating a symbology in csv format in qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289691/creating-a-symbology-in-csv-format-in-qgis)
- How do I do `<something>` that I could easily have learned how do to by googling the exact title of my question?

  - Example: [Editing shapefiles in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197273/editing-shapefiles-in-qgis)

In the second example, one of the comments actually says "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows very little research effort."

As it currently stands we're not giving the people who asked these questions clear feedback on why their question was closed. So, I think we should have a new close reason, **"This question does not show any research effort."**

Comment: When mods close it 'off topic' and we add another reason - it automatically goes to a comment "This question does not show any research effort."

Answer (score 3):

For a feature request such as this the first thing to clarify is whether you seek a new custom close reason for GIS SE, or a new Stack Exchange network-wide close reason.

For a new Stack Exchange network-wide close reason your question should be researched/asked at [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

For a new GIS SE custom close reason you need to take into account that we are only permitted three (see the current occupants of those slots below) and so you would need to propose which gets removed or how one may be amended to include your proposal.

[image]

My opinion, as an engaged user of this site, is that a new/modified close reason is not needed for this because there is already a mechanism to reduce the number of questions which "are perfectly clear and specific, yet not acceptable due to lack of effort", and that is to downvote them.  Such downvotes are inline with the downvote tool tip which starts:

> This question does not show any research effort

You could do that on both of your examples, or you could probably flag/vote for the first example to be closed using the first of our custom close reasons:

> When seeking help to debug/write/improve code always provide the
>   desired behavior, a specific problem/error and the shortest code (as
>   formatted text, not pictures) needed to reproduce it in the question
>   body. Providing a clear problem statement and a code attempt helps
>   others to help you.